# Find max value from generic arraylist

Tags: java

I want to write a method to find the max value of arraylist. It could be integer or double type.

I believe the below code works for arrays, but not for arraylist?

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T maxValue(T[] array){       
     T max = array[0];
     for(T data: array){
          if(data.compareTo(max)>0)
              max =data;                
     }
     return max;
}
```

Comment: "I believe the below code works for arrays, but not for arraylist?" have you tried, with the appropriate modifications (like the first line of the method where you need to use `get`)?

Comment: You would be well-served looking at the source code for Collections.max, given that that method does what you want. Or, use that method, and not reimplement it, of course.

Comment: This code finds the maximum in an array. Can you share the modifications you made to make it work for an `ArrayList` and explain where exactly you're stuck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(Collections.max(Arrays.asList(1, 3, 6, 2, 4, 5)));
    System.out.println(Collections.max(Arrays.asList(1.7D, 3.2D, 2.5D, 2.1D, 0.05D, 1.84D)));
}
```

How about this?

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(maxValue(Arrays.asList(1, 3, 6, 2, 4, 5)));
    System.out.println(maxValue(Arrays.asList(1.7D, 3.2D, 2.5D, 2.1D, 0.05D, 1.84D)));
}

public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T maxValue(List<T> array){
    T max = array.get(0);
    for(T data: array){
        if(data.compareTo(max)>0)
            max =data;
    }
    return max;
}
```

Also, your code works for arraylist if you change parameter type from T[] to List

Answer (score 4):

First, it *should* be `Comparable<? super T>`. Second, the argument needs to be a `Collection<T>` (or `List<T>`) instead of an array. Finally, there is the existing [`Collections.max(Collection<? extends T>)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#max(java.util.Collection)) that you can use to implement the method. Like,

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T maxValue(Collection<T> c) {
    return Collections.max(c);
}
```